# Integration Test Rails Error: undefined local variable or method "login_form_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, methods, integration-testing

I keep getting an error on:
My routes file has login_form already. What am I missing on? What is this error?

```
`<class:LoginTest>': undefined local variable or method `login_form_path' for LoginTest:Class (NameError)
```

In my login_test.rb, I have:

```
require 'test_helper'

class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @bob = user(:bob)
  end

  test 'bob can login' do
    get login_form_path
    assert_response :success

    login(@bob.email, 'abc123')

    assert_template 'show_user'
  end

  test 'bob cannot login with bad password'
    get login_form_path
    assert_response :success

    login(@bob.email, 'bad_password')

    assert_template 'login_form'
  end
```

In my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :logins
  resources :users
  root 'html#login_form'
  get '/login', to: 'html#login_form', as: :login_form
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create_session', as: :create_session
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy_session', as: :destroy_session
  get '/users/:id', to: 'html#show_user', as: :show_user
  get '/accounts/:id', to: 'html#show_account', as: :show_account
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `do` in your test: `test 'bob cannot login with bad password'`

```
test 'bob cannot login with bad password' do
  get login_form_path
  assert_response :success

  login(@bob.email, 'bad_password')

  assert_template 'login_form'
end
```

See the first example of the [ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html) API documentation for more information

Comment: That's a completely idiotic mistake lol Thanks for catching that. Now that's fixed, I'm getting another error on superclass mismatch for LoginTest as a type error....

Comment: Glad to help! :) Could you be more specific about the new error you are getting...

Comment: have you able to solve your issue with above solution?